# null is not an object(evaluating 'blob.data') fetch react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Soy nuevo en JS y estoy intentando usar Fetch para consumir servicios para una aplicación mobile.
Quiero poder hacer Catch cuando no haya conexión o no pueda acceder al servidor, etc...
en vez de poder agarrar el error, la app se cae con **null is not an object(evaluating 'blob.data')**

```
import GlobalURL from './Url';

export const getMailAvailability = async (mail) => {
    let url = GlobalURL +  mail;
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
    })
        .then(async (data) => {
            return await data.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

cabe decir que si hay conexión el fetch funciona perfectamente.

alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
import GlobalURL from "./Url";

export const getMailAvailability = async (mail) => {
  let url = GlobalURL + mail;
  await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {},
  })
    .then(async (data) => {
      return await data.json();
    })
    .then(async (data) => data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```